# Conditional distribution of Normal r.v.

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

Let X be N($\mu$,Q) with $\mu$= (1,1) and Q= $\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1 \\
1 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$.
I would like to find the distribution of Y = $X_1 + X_2$ given Z =  $X_1 - X_2 = 0$ .

Therefore I should obtain that Y = $2X_1$ or, equally, that Y = $2X_2$, but since they have a different variance I don't understand how it could be possible.

Continuing with the solution I should find $f_{Z=0}(y)$ being normal with $\mu=2$ and $\sigma^2=20/3$. But still I'm not able to obtain this result. 
Could someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All variables in your problem are normal, therefore all the information you need is encoded in the covariance matrix (and means).

You can first compute: 
$$Var(Y) = Var(X_1+X_2) = 3 + 2 + 2 = 7$$
and
$$Var(Z) = Var(X_1-X_2) = 3 + 2 - 2 = 3$$
and finally:
$$Cov(Y,Z) = Cov(X_1+X_2,X_1-X_2) = 3 - 1 + 1 - 2 = 1$$
This gives joint distribution of $Y,Z$ being normal
$ \mathcal{N}((2,0), \begin{bmatrix}
6 & 5 \\
5 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix} ) $

From this you can find pdf of $Y|Z=0$ explicitly and read off mean and variance.

Comment: you have: $Var(Y) = Var(X_1+X_2) = 3 + 2 + 1 = 6$ but should be $Var(Y) = Var(X_1+X_2) = 3 + 2 + 2 = 7$ because of $2*cov(X_1,X_2)$?

Comment: and in: $Cov(Y,Z) = Cov(X_1+X_2,X_1-X_2) = 3 - 1 + 1 - 2 = 5$, shouldn't be: $Cov(Y,Z) = Cov(X_1+X_2,X_1-X_2) = 3 + 1 - 1 - 2 = 1$

Comment: and third how do you know that (Y,Z) is Multivariate Normal. having each r.v. normal does not imply that the random vector is normal too

Comment: Ad 1. Yes it should be $2 Cov(A,B)$, already fixed.
Ad 2. Yes I made a typo, fixed again, thank you.
Ad 3. $(Y,Z)$ is a result of linear mapping of $(X_1,X_2)$ and linear maps preserve 'multivariate normalness'

Comment: what u are saying is that the linear combination of normal r.v. give raise always to multivariate normal? I didn't get this point. Please see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3376039/rn-r-v-with-each-component-normal-that-however-is-not-multivariate-normal?noredirect=1#comment6948204_3376039. There is the proof that what I said in the first row was a wrong question, I don't know if u meant that.

Comment: I'm *not* saying linear combination of just any normal r.v.'s is multivariate normal. It's precisely linear combination of *multivariate* normal r.v.'s (i.e. *jointly* normal) that are guaranteed to be multivariate normal again after linear mapping.